# I want to check at least one value in ng-repeat, if found, then to display <div> class

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

In my ng-repeat, scored/not scored are there. I want to display `<div>` class if at least one item in the ng-repeat has "Not Scored"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the code that you have tried so far, and we can help you get in the right direction. Initial thought is, since this is logic, you should be determining whether or not you show this class within your controller and set the boolean to a variable, which is then bound to `ng-show` on your div that contains the `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

You should be determining whether or not you are displaying that div inside your controller. Doing it within the `ng-repeat` would mean you would have logic in your view and that's just not good practice. Here is a simple example on how to accomplish what you're wanting.

In your controller:

```
$scope.showDiv = false;

$scope.getItems = function () {
    // fetch items via ajax...
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
        if (data.items[i].foo == 'Not Scored') {
            showDiv = true;
        }
    }
 }
```

And on your view:

```
<div ng-show="showDiv">
    // do your ng-repeat here
</div>
```